# How to merge two queryset based on common key name in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have 2 QuerySet:

`<Queryset [a, b, c]>` and `<Queryset [a, d, e]>`

How can I merge those two to achieve:

`<Queryset [a, b, c, d, e]>`

Edit with real case:

```
qs_home = Match.objects.filter(competition=competition) \
    .values(name=F("home_team__name")) \
    .annotate(home_win=Sum(Case(When(home_score__gt=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_draw=Sum(Case(When(home_score=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_lose=Sum(Case(When(home_score__lt=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_goal=Sum('home_score')) \
    .annotate(home_conceded=Sum('away_score')) \
    .annotate(home_point=Sum(Case(
        When(home_score__gt=F('away_score'), then=3),
        When(home_score=F('away_score'), then=1)
    ))) \
    .order_by('home_team__name')
qs_away = Match.objects.filter(competition=competition) \
    .values(name=F("away_team__name")) \
    .annotate(away_win=Sum(Case(When(away_score__gt=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_draw=Sum(Case(When(away_score=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_lose=Sum(Case(When(away_score__lt=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_goal=Sum('away_score')) \
    .annotate(away_conceded=Sum('home_score')) \
    .annotate(away_point=Sum(Case(
        When(away_score__gt=F('home_score'), then=3),
        When(away_score=F('home_score'), then=1)
    ))) \
    .order_by('away_team__name')
```

If i do `qs_home.union(qs_away)` the `qs_away` just append at the end of `qs_home` with the key from `qs_home` but the value of `qs_away`

Edit : My Workaround

```
for qs in qs_home:
    away_dict = next((item for item in qs_away if item['name'] == qs['name']), None)
    qs['away_win'] = away_dict['away_win']
    qs['away_draw'] = away_dict['away_draw']
    qs['away_lose'] = away_dict['away_lose']
    qs['away_goal'] = away_dict['away_goal']
    qs['away_conceded'] = away_dict['away_conceded']
    qs['away_point'] = away_dict['away_point']
```

this will append all the `away_` key and value to `qs_home`. But of course im trying to avoid for loop if possible.

if im using `union()`, lets say, the len of `qs_home` and `qs_away` both 18. I get the queryset with 36 length. I want the length of the new queryset just 18 with the key, value append to each dict with the same name

Updated with my model:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='matches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gameweek = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_matches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_matches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    away_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    STATUS = Choices(
        (1, 'not_started', 'Not Started'),
        (2, 'half_time', 'Half Time'),
        (3, 'full_time', 'Full Time'),
        (9, 'postponed', 'Postponed')
    )
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS.not_started)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union) and by looking at your queryset example, it also seems you want unique values, so try the following:

```py
q1 = Model.objects.filter(name__in=['a', 'b', 'c'])
q2 = Model.objects.filter(name__in=['a', 'd', 'e'])
combined_qs = q1.union(q2)
```

This will return a new queryset that contains all distinct elements from both `q1` and `q2` In your case, it will be:

```py
<QuerySet [a, b, c, d, e]>
```

### Edit

You can make the loop more concise by using Python's built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#zip)
function to iterate through the two QuerySets together and updating the first one with the values from the second one, like so following:

```py
qs_home = Match.objects.filter(competition=competition) \
    .values(name=F("home_team__name")) \
    .annotate(home_win=Sum(Case(When(home_score__gt=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_draw=Sum(Case(When(home_score=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_lose=Sum(Case(When(home_score__lt=F('away_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(home_goal=Sum('home_score')) \
    .annotate(home_conceded=Sum('away_score')) \
    .annotate(home_point=Sum(Case(
        When(home_score__gt=F('away_score'), then=3),
        When(home_score=F('away_score'), then=1)
    ))) \
    .order_by('home_team__name')
    
qs_away = Match.objects.filter(competition=competition) \
    .values(name=F("away_team__name")) \
    .annotate(away_win=Sum(Case(When(away_score__gt=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_draw=Sum(Case(When(away_score=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_lose=Sum(Case(When(away_score__lt=F('home_score'), then=1)))) \
    .annotate(away_goal=Sum('away_score')) \
    .annotate(away_conceded=Sum('home_score')) \
    .annotate(away_point=Sum(Case(
        When(away_score__gt=F('home_score'), then=3),
        When(away_score=F('home_score'), then=1)
    ))) \
    .order_by('away_team__name')
    
for home_dict, away_dict in zip(qs_home, qs_away):
    home_dict.update(away_dict)
    
merged_qs = qs_home
```

Comment: updated with my real case, kindly check please

Comment: it didnt seem to work either

Comment: @AndiFathulMukminin What output does it return and you want what kind of output?

Comment: please check my edit on my workaround what im trying to achieve, im trying to avoid the for loop if possible @SunderamDubey

Comment: @AndiFathulMukminin Can you also share relevant models, so that I could see the actual field names?

Comment: updated with my model class @SunderamDubey

Comment: it return an error `'dict' object has no attribute '_combinator_query'`

Comment: @AndiFathulMukminin Do you want a solution from loop or without it?

Comment: @AndiFathulMukminin See I dumped the code [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/sql/ZAQ3EwcW7H_h6Trr) at code dump, if works for you then I'd edit my answer.

Comment: tbh, idk which way is the best practice. if for loop is the best way as pragmatic as it seems, so it be

Comment: i try the code at your code dump. and it works. thanks man for the times and effort, you should update the your answer

Comment: okay bro, will do